# Unable to resolve host "API ADDRESS" no address associated with this hostname

Tags: android, https

I want to send a https post request that contains two headers and two body arguments to access my API but i get this error !

Unable to resolve host "API ADDRESS" no address associated with hostname

can someone helSp me please ?

Comment: Did you check your internet connectivity ?

Comment: Yes, i added the internet permission in the manifext.xml and internet is working :/

Comment: I didn't mean that. If network issue in your device you will get this error. This is one possible option

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Please post the whole log around `Unable to resolve host "API ADDRESS" no address associated with hostname`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like below or check your Internet connection. i know i am late but it will help others.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```